# SignalR and Android Webview

Tags: .net, android-webview, signalr

I have a .NET web application which uses SignalR to push data to the active clients.

Now we are planning to wrap this web application as an android application. If i simply load the application in Android webview will still my SignalR pushes continue to work?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes, it should still work. Phonegap uses a similar technique.